# How to do reverse order SUM Total in Gidview RowDataBound using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Below is my gridview:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gv_TotalAllReg" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gv_TotalAllReg_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="dt" CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sno" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#f1f1f1">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="dt" DataFormatString="{0:MM-dd-yyyy}" HeaderText="Date" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="New Registrations">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Registrations" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cumulative Registrations">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_CumulativeRegistrations" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>

                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Below I am trying to achieve the counts.

I am showing Date wise new Registrations but I need Cumulative Registrations base on new registrations:

```
 Sno    Date           New Registrations      Cumulative Registrations
  1     12-23-2016          2
  2     12-24-2016          6
  3     12-25-2016          1
```

I need output like below and Cumulative Registration means I have created one function for display dates from 23 to 25 december 2016. So base on date getting new registration and also i want to display cumulative registrations base on new registration, base on new registration adding cum registration and how to achieve cum registration add reverse order in RowDataBound .

```
 Sno    Date           New Registrations      Cumulative Registrations
  1     12-25-2016          2                         9
  2     12-24-2016          6                         7
  3     12-23-2016          1                         1
```

Below I have code and counts for ascending order adding but I need to add reverse order

```
 int total = 0;
  protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the current row to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //add the registrations to the total
        total += Convert.ToInt32(row["Registrations"]);

        //find the label in the row with findcontrol and cast it back to one
        Label label = e.Row.FindControl("lbl_CumulativeRegistrations") as Label;

        //fill the label with the current total
        label.Text = string.Format("{0:N0}", total);
    }
}
```

I am geting output like below ascending format

```
 Cumulative Registrations
        2
        8
        9
```

Comment: That's the correct output....

Comment: I need to add descending order from down to up. @Legends

Comment: order your data by the date field desc and bind the grid.

Comment: 0+1=1,1+6=7 and 7+2=9 like that to add cum registration. @Legends

Comment: For cum registration we are not binding just using  //add the registrations to the total
        total += Convert.ToInt32(row["Registrations"]);

        //find the label in the row with findcontrol and cast it back to one
        Label label = e.Row.FindControl("lbl_CumulativeRegistrations") as Label;

        //fill the label with the current total
        label.Text = string.Format("{0:N0}", total); .@Legends

Comment: I got date descending but I need cum registration descending because its not coming from sql query and com registration adding with new registration. @Legends

Comment: I don't understand you right now. When you sort your grid data by "date descending", then you get 25,24,23 and the cumulative counts should be 1, 7, 9. So you sort the data before you bind it to the grid.

Comment: Sorry I added check my updated question, Also I am getting like that for cum registration column 2,8,9 but it should be 9,7,1 should add reverse order. @Legends

Comment: I am binding dates separately using one function like  from date 23 and to date 25 to that sql function thats why cum registration will not sort be desc. @Legends

Comment: The 25th day has one registration or two?

Comment: just I am giving example suppose 25 has 2 registration ,24 has 6 and 23 has 1 registration and I need output like. 9,7,1 adding by descending using new registration. @Legends

Comment: Can you update your anwer will help ful for me and already I got one answer below please suggest using that also. @Legends

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133443/discussion-between-legends-and-mmk).

Answer (score 1):

this code adding a new column to your datasource(datatable) and sum all registirations.

you can put before gridview databinding and remove ItemDatabound method.

```
        //tbl is your datasoure (DataTable)
        tbl.Columns.Add("TotalRegistration", typeof(long));
        long total = 0;
        for (int i = tbl.Rows.Count -1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            total += (int)tbl.Rows[i]["Registrations"]; // if columnd type is not int, use Convert.ToInt32
            tbl.Rows[i]["TotalRegistration"] = total;
        }
```